# Orbital angular momentum in weak interaction

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, standard-model, weak-interaction, pions

I am bit confused with a statement in Griffiths where he talks about the decay of pions by weak interaction to muons and neutrino. Here, he says that if angular momentum of muon and neutrino is present then it is perpendicular to their direction of motion (velocity). How do we come up with such conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orbital angular momentum is $\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$ just like macroscopic angular momentum, and there is a built-in assumption that you are taking the position relative the center of mass of the particles.

The cross-product means that the result is at right angles to the 
inputs including the momentum which is co-linear with the velocity. Finally, conservation of momentum forces the momenta of all the daughters to be co-planar in the CoM frame.